# Free web host for WordPress blog

Tags: hosting-recommendation

Is there any free web hosting site host the wordpress blog?

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com/)! Of course, it has downsides (no plugins, limited themes, etc). But it has the added benefit of constant, automatic updates, reliable infrastructure and, well, it's free.

If you plan on running a self-hosted WordPress blog, the biggest mistake you can make is to skimp on hosting, and I'd strongly advise against using a "free" host. Security, performance and uptime are all dramatically affected by your choice of host.

Comment: Take it from someone who tried numerous free hosts, they won't cut it with WordPress and the provider is under zero obligation to give you any kind of reliable service. My time using free hosts was brief, i've tried a good 5 or 6 all with terrible results. So i opted for using WordPress.com for my blog(not that i do much at all), but it works great and i'll never bother with free hosting again(it's seriously not worth the pain).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look for a cheap but premium hosting provider, but the free option is not a problem, 9lessons done it with just 1$, learn more [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/04/just-one-dollar-invested-on-9lessons.html).